# Laravel backpack addField where clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Using this [link](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/806).

I tried to add a where clause in addField where the dropdown should load the contents as options only if they match a condition.

Here is the code:

```
$this->crud->addField([ // select_from_array
        'name' => 'manager',
        'label' => "Manager Name",
        'type' => 'select_callback', // Custom field type of select2
        'entity' => 'Manager',
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'model' => 'App\Models\Manager',
        'scope' => 'manager'
        // 'allows_multiple' => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
    ], 'update/create/both');
```

And in Model.php

```
public function scopeManager($query)
{
    return $query->where('gym_code', Auth::user()->gym_code);
}
```

But it is not working!!
Thanks

Comment: what is the error message? what is not working?

Comment: Take a look at this - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No error message it is not working

Comment: I want to just load the options of select from the table on the basis of a condition stored in the table. Like if the gymcode is same as of logged in user then retrieve the name of the manager of that gymcode and show it as a option in select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the same link that I suggested in Question.

In the link **@thplat** answered a change in select_callback.blade.php

`For the select_callback view I took the select view and changed only one line there.
We go from: 
@foreach ($field['model']::all() as $connected_entity_entry) to @foreach ((isset($field['callback']) ? $field['callback']() : $field['model']::all()) as $connected_entity_entry).`